# Image SEO - always repeat main keyword in alt text?

Tags: seo, html, images

I'm working on an Easter Island website and I'm currently redesigning my image system. Virtually all my photos are of Easter Island. My question is, should I always include the keywords "Easter Island" for Google to easier understand that my photos are from Easter Island, or is it sufficient that the "Easter Island" keywords are in the domain, as well as in all other pages of the site?

For example,

Alt text 1: "Moai statues at volcano Rano Raraku at Easter Island (Rapa Nui)"

or

Alt text 2: "Moai statues at volcano Rano Raraku"

Would example 1 be considered keyword stuffing by Google

Comment: No keyword stuffing with "alt text 1". But I advice you to fill the alt attribute with pertinent visible words in case of image is not loaded. Don't think about SEO and think about web users.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll go with no. 1 then since being more descriptive in this case wouldn't confuse the users - rather on the contrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are including a lot of information in the alt text not just the keyword 'Easter Island' I don't think Google will consider it keyword stuffing.

Ultimately the best way to rank for images is to have well optimised h1 tags on the pages that the images are displayed on.

In my opinion the more information the better, I'd go with 'alt text 1'

Comment: Thanks, I'll go with no. 1 then. This is what it's looking like right now:
http://www.easterislandtraveling.com/media/images/archaeology/moai-statues-rano-raraku-sunrise/
Alt tags don't apply yet and the low res photos aren't final of course, but still gives an idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Thumb rule is to go for naturally looking sentence. So Alt text 2 is fine, while the first one is spam and will be definitely caught and punished ( by Penguin update at least).
When working on a new site you should always build a very natural site meant for the visitors. Later slowly you can start making the changes and see the results.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google official Guideline](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=114016) this is considered *keyword stuffing*:

```
<img src="puppy.jpg" alt="puppy dog baby dog pup pups puppies doggies pups litter puppies dog retriever labrador wolfhound setter pointer puppy jack russell terrier 
puppies dog food cheap dogfood puppy food">
```

Which is not your case. You are actully simply adding the name of `Easter Island (Rapa Nui)` to pictures that are really showing parts of the island.

Anyway if I were you I would not abuse it; in other words, I would not add in every single `alt` the words "Easter Island (Rapa Nui)". But this is just my feeling about SEO from my previous experience, it's not stated anywhere.